# How can I quantify the impact of the lag between two events that each occurred twice?

Tags: forecasting

There's a question about the impact of holding sales close to one another. Last year, Sale A was held four weeks before Sale B. This year, Sale A was held three weeks before Sale B. How would I go about determining if the increased proximity of the two sales this year negatively affected sales in Sale B? And if so, could I then determine the minimum time between sales in order to eliminate the negative impact?

Comment: Not a lot you can do with 2 data points.

Comment: @mkt  I think that could be an answer, with a bit of explanation.

Comment: @PeterFlom Thanks, I've attempted to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have two data points, one for each year. Unfortunately, lots of things may be different between those two years that affected the sales (changes in the economy, heat waves that can reduce shopping activity, other random year-to-year fluctuations, and so on).

If you had a lot more data points, you might be able to use the additional information to distinguish between the differences caused by the lag between sales and the differences caused by other factors. Since you do not, this is not likely to work out.

But technically what you describe is not impossible, though it's not likely to be illuminating. You could write a Bayesian model that describes variation in sales as a function of lag between sales and other factors. Part of doing this involves defining prior distributions that capture your belief in how each of the factors influences sales. This model could in principle be fitted with your two data points. But this is not really likely to tell you anything new - your model output (the posterior) will most probably reflect your input (the prior distributions that you defined). Your data are insufficient to meaningfully influence the outcome, unless the values are shockingly unexpected i.e. far more or less than you had reason to believe beforehand.